# Parsing Vector Data using Jackson

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

I am using Jackson and I'm facing some issues while parsing the data vector.
My JSON is something like:

```
{"Values": [[1,2],[3,4]]}
```

How can I parse this through Jackson?

I do not want to use any case class/POJO class to accomplish this.
It would be great if a Tree Model can be used.

Comment: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various node types provided by Jackson. Here is an example and output using `jackson-core-2.5.0`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String json = "{\"Values\": [[1,2],[3,4]]}";
        final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
        final JsonNode values = jsonNode.get("Values");
        System.out.println(jsonNode.getNodeType());
        System.out.println(values.getNodeType());
        System.out.println(values.isArray());
        values.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OBJECT
ARRAY
true
[1,2]
[3,4]
```